# Trying to identify some small flat flex cable connectors on a Nintendo Switch motherboard

Tags: connector

I recently bought a faulty Nintendo Switch console which somebody had already looked at - it has two broken flat flex cable connectors.

I have the tools, equipment and the skills to replace these BUT I'm not familiar with FFC connector types so am having difficulty finding replacements.

The following page has some decent photos of the motherboard -

https://www.unitechnix.de/reparaturanleitungen/nintendo-switch.php

If you look at this photo (the smaller, blown up image to the right) -

[image]

at the far left of the smaller photo you'll see one of the connectors that I'm after (it handles the FFC for the left Joycon connector) - there are eleven pins

As for the other connector, it handles the FFC for the fan - take a look at this photo -

[image]

look to the bottom of the photo at the thinner 'tongue' of the PCB (reminds me a bit of Florida!) - there's two small, white FFC connectors. One has a black locking tab, the other a grey locking tab. It's the one with the grey locking tab that I'm after. There are four pins.

What kind of connector is this and what is the process to look up a similar unknown connector in the future

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a valid EE question?

Comment: It would be easier for us if you put the images directly in your question. Have you already tried returning the faulty device?

Comment: I've provided links to photos of the board with the parts in place. The device is also out of warranty and paying for a repair isn't cost effective.